# Using a filterService in a controller

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on some Angular 1.1.5 code about a year old. I have a `filterService` that I'm using in a template but want to move into the controller.

Service:

```
myapp.factory('filterService', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
  var model = {
    // ...
    },
  }

  var service = {
    characteristic: function(target) {
      if (model.characteristicsChecked["checkedCount"] == 0) {
        return true;
      }
      else {
        var passesFilter = false;
        angular.forEach(target.characteristics, function(char) {
          passesFilter = passesFilter || model.characteristicsChecked[char.slug];
        });
        return passesFilter;
      }
    },
    //...
  }
  service.model = model;
  return service;
}]);
```

Each element in `myCollection` has an array of characteristics, and `characteristicsChecked` is bound to checkboxes in the template. This works in the template like:

```
{{ $parent.prefiltered = (myCollection | filter:characteristic) }}
```

but the app has a lot of similar filters and the data rarely changes, so it's too slow to run them with every digest cycle. How can I use the `characteristic` filter on `$scope.myCollection` in a controller?

**Edit**

I've tried this:

```
$filter('filter')($scope.myCollection, filterService.characteristic);
```

But get the following error that I don't understand well:

```
TypeError: object is not a function
    at new <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/assets/app/controllers/filters.js?body=1:24:33)
    at invoke (http://localhost:3000/assets/unstable/angular.js?body=1:2932:28)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:3000/assets/unstable/angular.js?body=1:2944:23)
    at http://localhost:3000/assets/unstable/angular.js?body=1:5369:28
    at c (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular-ui-router.min.js?body=1:8:7666)
    at u.link (http://localhost:3000/assets/angular-ui-router.min.js?body=1:8:8049)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/assets/unstable/angular.js?body=1:4960:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/assets/unstable/angular.js?body=1:4551:15)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/assets/unstable/angular.js?body=1:4554:13)
    at publicLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/assets/unstable/angular.js?body=1:4456:30) <div class="span3" ui-view="filters">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the [`$filter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) service as dependency to your controller and then use it like this:

```
$filter('filter')($scope.myCollection, filterService.characteristic);
```

(Note that the `filterService` must also be added as dependency)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tried that syntax and a few similar things, but get a `TypeError` I added to the question above.

Comment: Can you post the `filters.js` content?

Comment: Its' a long file, but line 24 is the line in the edit above (the syntax you suggested). The original unedited file is here: http://dpaste.com/00T393Q

Comment: The dependency order is wrong. You have `'$scope', '$stateParams', '$timeout', '$filter', '$rootScope', ...` but on the function signature the order is `$scope, $stateParams, $timeout, $rootScope, $filter, ...`. Swap `$rootScope` with `$filter`.

Comment: Wow. Thank you. That resolves the error, but the filtered collection in the controller on line 24 is an empty array. I've confirmed that the filter is returning `true` from the line `model.characteristicsChecked["checkedCount"] == 0` on page load, and `$scope.stoves` is populated.

Comment: On line 23 add this: `console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.stoves));` and let's know what it prints.

Comment: It prints `[]` even though in the filters.html partial `{{ stoves }}` is an array of objects as expected. I see this is a `$scope` issue so I'm going to mark this correct and make a separate question. Thank you again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61568/discussion-between-thebenedict-and-bmleite).

Answer (score 1):

Please see documention here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

```
app.controller('someCtrl', function($scope,filterFilter,filterService){   

 $scope.myCollection =  [...];

  $scope.prefiltered  = filterFilter($scope.myCollection,filterService.characteristic)

});
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried a similar syntax but get an error (added to the question). Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: @thebenedict please create plunkr otherwise id difficult to advise